# Fastlane screengrab on Android 30 emulator

Tags: android, storage, screenshot, android-permissions, fastlane

I'm trying to setup fastlane screengrab to auto generate screenshots for my app in different languages.

I'm running an AVD with API 30 and it looks like creating the screenshot is working well, because i can finde the file inside the Device File Explorer. But i can't make it to work running `bundle exec fastlane screengrab`

It's always resulting in'Permission denied' or 'No such file or directory' errors. Has anybody managed to successfully pull the created screenshots from the emulator to a local directory?

Here is the output i receive:

```
 [12:57:57]: WARNING: fastlane requires your locale to be set to UTF-8. To learn more go to https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#set-up-environment-variables
    Der Befehl "cat" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
    konnte nicht gefunden werden.
    [12:58:03]: Successfully loaded 'D:/Workspace/MyApp/fastlane/Screengrabfile' 

+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                        Detected Values from './fastlane/Screengrabfile'                        |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| android_home               | $PATH                                                             |
| use_adb_root               | true                                                              |
| app_package_name           | packagename                                                |
| app_apk_path               | app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk                         |
| tests_apk_path             | app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk |
| locales                    | ["de-DE", "en-US"]                                                |
| clear_previous_screenshots | true                                                              |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

[12:58:03]: Using `adb` found at adb which is not within the specified ANDROID_HOME at $PATH
[12:58:03]: Using `aapt` found at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2/aapt.EXE which is not within the specified ANDROID_HOME at $PATH

+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                 Summary for screengrab 2.162.0                                  |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| tests_package_name          | packagename.test                                           |
| android_home                | $PATH                                                             |
| locales                     | ["de-DE", "en-US"]                                                |
| clear_previous_screenshots  | true                                                              |
| output_directory            | fastlane/metadata/android                                         |
| skip_open_summary           | true                                                              |
| app_package_name            | packagename                                                |
| test_instrumentation_runner | androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner                           |
| ending_locale               | en-US                                                             |
| use_adb_root                | true                                                              |
| app_apk_path                | app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk                         |
| tests_apk_path              | app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk |
| device_type                 | phone                                                             |
| exit_on_test_failure        | true                                                              |
| reinstall_app               | false                                                             |
| use_timestamp_suffix        | true                                                              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

[12:58:03]: Limiting the test classes run by `screengrab` to just those that generate screenshots can make runs faster.
[12:58:03]: Consider using the :use_tests_in_classes or :use_tests_in_packages option, and organize your tests accordingly.
[12:58:03]: Clearing phoneScreenshots within fastlane/metadata/android
[12:58:03]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE
[12:58:03]: ▸ /sdcard
[12:58:03]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 root
[12:58:03]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
[12:58:03]: Cleaning screenshots on device
ls: /sdcard/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images/screenshots: Permission denied
[12:58:03]: Exit status: 1
ls: /sdcard/packagename/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: Permission denied
[12:58:03]: Exit status: 1
[12:58:03]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell run-as packagename rm -rf /data/user/0/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images/screenshots
ls: /data/data/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:03]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/packagename/app_screengrab/de-DE/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:04]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:04]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/user/0/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:04]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:04]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/packagename/app_screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:04]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/packagename/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:04]: Exit status: 1
[12:58:04]: Validating app APK
[12:58:04]: $ C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2/aapt.EXE dump permissions app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
[12:58:04]: ▸ package: packagename
[12:58:04]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD'
[12:58:04]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
[12:58:04]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
[12:58:04]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
[12:58:04]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION'
[12:58:04]: Installing app APK
[12:58:04]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 install -t -r app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
[12:58:04]: ▸ Performing Streamed Install
[12:58:04]: ▸ Success
[12:58:04]: Installing tests APK
[12:58:04]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 install -t -r app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk
[12:58:05]: ▸ Performing Streamed Install
[12:58:05]: ▸ Success
[12:58:05]: Granting the permission necessary to change locales on the device
[12:58:05]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm grant packagename android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
[12:58:05]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
[12:58:05]: ▸ 30
[12:58:05]: Granting the permissions necessary to access device external storage
[12:58:05]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm grant packagename android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
[12:58:05]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm grant packagename android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
[12:58:05]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
[12:58:06]: ▸ 30
[12:58:06]: $ C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2/aapt.EXE dump badging app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
[12:58:06]: ▸ package: name='packagename' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0' compileSdkVersion='30' compileSdkVersionCodename='11'
[12:58:06]: ▸ sdkVersion:'29'
[12:58:06]: ▸ targetSdkVersion:'30'
[12:58:06]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD'
[12:58:06]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
[12:58:06]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
[12:58:06]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
[12:58:06]: ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-af:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-am:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ar:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-as:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-az:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-be:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-bg:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-bn:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-bs:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ca:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-cs:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-da:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-de:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-el:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-en-AU:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-en-CA:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-en-GB:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-en-IN:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-en-US:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-en-XC:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-es:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-es-US:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-et:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-eu:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-fa:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-fi:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-fr:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-fr-CA:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-gl:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-gu:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-hi:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-hr:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-hu:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-hy:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-in:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-is:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-it:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-iw:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ja:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ka:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-kk:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-km:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-kn:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ko:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ky:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-lo:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-lt:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-lv:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-mk:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ml:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-mn:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-mr:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ms:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-my:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-nb:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ne:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-nl:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-or:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-pa:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-pl:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-pt:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-pt-BR:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-pt-PT:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ro:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ru:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-si:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-sk:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-sl:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-sq:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-sr:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-sr-Latn:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-sv:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-sw:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ta:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-te:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-th:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-tl:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-tr:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-uk:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-ur:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-uz:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-vi:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-zh-CN:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-zh-HK:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-zh-TW:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-label-zu:'MyApp'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-icon-160:'res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-icon-240:'res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-icon-320:'res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-icon-480:'res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-icon-640:'res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-icon-65534:'res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application: label='MyApp' icon='res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml'
[12:58:06]: ▸ testOnly='-1'
[12:58:06]: ▸ application-debuggable
[12:58:06]: ▸ launchable-activity: name='packagename.MainActivity'  label='MyApp' icon=''
[12:58:06]: ▸ feature-group: label=''
[12:58:06]: ▸   uses-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch'
[12:58:06]: ▸   uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch' reason='default feature for all apps'
[12:58:06]: ▸ main
[12:58:06]: ▸ supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
[12:58:06]: ▸ supports-any-density: 'true'
[12:58:06]: ▸ locales: '--_--' 'af' 'am' 'ar' 'as' 'az' 'be' 'bg' 'bn' 'bs' 'ca' 'cs' 'da' 'de' 'el' 'en-AU' 'en-CA' 'en-GB' 'en-IN' 'en-US' 'en-XC' 'es' 'es-US' 'et' 'eu' 'fa' 'fi' 'fr' 'fr-CA' 'gl' 'gu' 'hi' 'hr' 'hu' 'hy' 'in' 'is' 'it' 'iw' 'ja' 'ka' 'kk' 'km' 'kn' 'ko' 'ky' 'lo' 'lt' 'lv' 'mk' 'ml' 'mn' 'mr' 'ms' 'my' 'nb' 'ne' 'nl' 'or' 'pa' 'pl' 'pt' 'pt-BR' 'pt-PT' 'ro' 'ru' 'si' 'sk' 'sl' 'sq' 'sr' 'sr-Latn' 'sv' 'sw' 'ta' 'te' 'th' 'tl' 'tr' 'uk' 'ur' 'uz' 'vi' 'zh-CN' 'zh-HK' 'zh-TW' 'zu'
[12:58:06]: ▸ densities: '160' '240' '320' '480' '640' '65534'
[12:58:06]: Running tests for locale: de-DE
[12:58:06]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument --no-window-animation -w \
-e testLocale de_DE \
-e endingLocale en_US \
-e appendTimestamp true \
packagename.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
[12:58:20]: ▸ packagename.ExampleInstrumentedTest:...
[12:58:20]: ▸ Time: 11.34
[12:58:20]: ▸ OK (3 tests)
[12:58:20]: Pulling captured screenshots for locale de-DE from the device
ls: /sdcard/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images/screenshots: Permission denied
[12:58:20]: Exit status: 1
ls: /sdcard/packagename/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: Permission denied
[12:58:20]: Exit status: 1
[12:58:20]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 pull /data/user/0/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images/screenshots C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/d20201009-22720-woz01y
adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/data/user/0/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images/screenshots': Permission denied
[12:58:20]: Exit status: 1
[12:58:20]: PERMISSION DENIED
[12:58:20]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell run-as packagename 'tar -cC /data/user/0/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images screenshots' | tar -xvC C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/d20201009-22720-woz01y
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '\\.\tape0'
run-as: exec failed for tar -cC /data/user/0/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:20]: Exit status: 1
[12:58:21]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 pull /data/data/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images/screenshots C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/d20201009-22720-woz01y
adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/data/data/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images/screenshots': Permission denied
[12:58:21]: Exit status: 1
[12:58:21]: PERMISSION DENIED
[12:58:21]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell run-as packagename 'tar -cC /data/data/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images screenshots' | tar -xvC C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/d20201009-22720-woz01y
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '\\.\tape0'
run-as: exec failed for tar -cC /data/data/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:21]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/packagename/app_screengrab/de-DE/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:21]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/packagename/screengrab/de-DE/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:21]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/user/0/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:21]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/packagename/files/packagename/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:21]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/packagename/app_screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:21]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/packagename/screengrab/en-US/images/screenshots: No such file or directory
[12:58:21]: Exit status: 1
[12:58:21]: Make sure you've used Screengrab.screenshot() in your tests and that your expected tests are being run.

[!] No screenshots were detected ❌
[12:58:21]: WARNING: fastlane requires your locale to be set to UTF-8. To learn more go to https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#set-up-environment-variables
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with android build tools equivalent to 30.0.x and similar to be compatible with the API version 30 for screengrab.

Comment: Unfortunately using build tools 30.0.3 and latest fastlane version doesn't help. Still get the same permission denied error on try to copy the screenshots from the emulator. As i mentioned in my question, i can find the created screenshots on the emulator, using the device file explorer.

Comment: I know this doesnt solve the actual problem but for the sake of trying , could you install fastlane independenly on the host server i.e. not via gemfile but say brew install fastlane and try your command without bundler ? I did face the same issue you were facing. But with trying non en-US locale , matching emulator version and fastlane installed via Homebrew worked for me. I am on latest fastlane version.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do that on a windows notebook. Could you explain the tasks in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these in your `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<!-- Allows unlocking your device and activating its screen so UI tests can succeed -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<!-- Allows for storing and retrieving screenshots -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Allows changing locales -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
```